# How can I write integration tests for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a chrome extension which loads in the developer window. It communicates with the currently loaded webpage and stores the desired data in the database.

I want to write automated unit test for this extension in node using selenium, phantomjs/chromedriver, mocha and chai.
I have written a simple test using selenium, chromedriver, mocha and chai. It is failing right now. I have attached the error below.

This is how it looks:
client.js

```
exports.client = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs').remote({
    // Settings
    // Use webdriverjs to create a Selenium Client
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
            args: [],
            extensions: ['/Users/Divyanshu/Downloads/STM_UPDATED_20160308051700.crx']
        }
    },
    logLevel: 'silent'
});
```

test.js

```
var client = require('./client').client;
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Test stackoverflow.com', function(){
    before(function(done) {
        client.init().url('chrome-extension://bfedbpidmfabedhnemcibiciahnjdnid/index.html', done);
    });

    describe('Check homepage', function(){
        it('should see the correct title', function(done) {
            client.getTitle(function(err, title){
                expect(title).to.have.string(
                    'STM'
                );
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should see the body', function(done) {
            client.getText('#header', function(err, span){
                expect(span).to.have.string(
                    'Browser'
                );
                done();
            })
        });
    });

    after(function(done) {
        client.end();
        done();
    });
});
```

This is how I am running selenium server:
`java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver`

And this is how I am running my test:
`mocha test.js -t 10000`

But I am not able to load my extension and getting these error:
Error output of test run:

```
Test stackoverflow.com
[13:08:00]:  COMMAND    POST     {"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:4444","port":"4444","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session","path":"/wd/hub/session","href":"http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session"}
[13:08:00]:  DATA        {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","version":"","javascriptEnabled":true,"platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome","args":[],"extensions":["/Users/Divyanshu/Downloads/STM_UPDATED_20160308051700.crx"]}}}
[13:08:00]:  ERROR  UnknownError    An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
            unknown error: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: cannot base64 decode
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

[13:08:00]:  ERROR  Couldn't get a session ID - undefined
    1) "before all" hook

[13:08:00]:  COMMAND    DELETE   {"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:4444","port":"4444","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session/","path":"/wd/hub/session/","href":"http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/"}
[13:08:00]:  DATA        {}

  0 passing (730ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test stackoverflow.com "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: [init()] <= 
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
      at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/utils/makeError.js:9:17)
      at RequestHandler.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
      at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs/node_modules/request/request.js:122:22)
      at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs/node_modules/request/request.js:1019:14)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs/node_modules/request/request.js:970:12)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
```

Error output in selenium server: `Exception: unknown error: cannot process extension #1`

I used `fs.readFileSync('/Users/Divyanshu/Downloads/STM_UPDATED_20160308051700.crx', 'base64')` to encode my crx file to overcome this error and got the error:

`Exception: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions`

I then tried to load the extension without crx file. Added this in 'args' in 'chromeOptions':

`args: ['load-extension=/Users/Divyanshu/Downloads/STM_UPDATED_20160308051700']`

This helped me in resolving the error: `cannot process extension #1`

But now I have stumbled upon new error. I am not able to load my html file (index.html). Its saying "Your file was not found. It may have been moved or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Reload". How can I over come this error?

This is how my manifest.json file looks:

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "description": "Tool.",
    "icons": {
        "16":  "icons/icon16.png",
        "48":  "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "<all_urls>",
        "history",
        "background",
        "storage",
        "cookies",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background-script.js",
            "panes/js/jquery.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "panes/*"
    ]
}
```

and this is my devtools.js file which I load from an html file where I have specified the location of devtools.html:

```
var panelWindow, injectedPanel = false, injectedPage = false,
    panelVisible = false, savedStack = [];

chrome.devtools.panels.create("Extension", "panes/img/logo.jpg",
    "panes/index.html", function(panel) {});
```

So, my extension has multiple html files. And I want to write unit tests for all those, moving past each file one by one, like, first I have to log into my extension (this is login.html), then I will select a client (this is selectClient.html) etc etc.

index.html loads first as you can see from the devtools.js, from where all the processing starts and loads other html files one by one.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are writing integration tests, not unit tests.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. :)